# How to specify linked resource folder in mxmlc compiler arguments?

Tags: apache-flex, mxmlc

I've got external folder with resources (graphics, movies, etc) which is shared between a couple of projects. I'm able to link this resource folder in FlashBuilder (as described in http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_5.html#155069). After that all the pathes to embeds are relative to the project, and that's the behaviour I want.

This linked resource appears in `.project` file as follows:

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>resources</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>DOCUMENTS/Shared/resources</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

Note, that it isn't source folder and it is not included in `compilerSourcePath` tag.

**The question is how can I specify resource linked folder in mxmlc command line arguments?**

`-source-path` is not working here, relative pathes to embeds can not be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible and there's no such option. FlashBuilder somehow passes all the workaround to mxmlc java wrapper, therefore it knows where to search resources.

In my project I used another method to achieve proper sharing of resources:

1. Autobuild step, which copies images and extractes fla files to resource folder in each project form the source directory.
2. All css files I moved to shared source folder (e.g. `Common/css/main.css`) - they are under source control. I added link to it via `-source-path` option.
3. After that all relative pathes in css started to look like `../../resources/image.png` in both projects.

Maybe someone will find my experience helpful.